# Не могу спрятать порт Apache

Tags: php, apache, nginx, сервер, ip

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, мне нужно чтобы сайт открывался по ip на веб-сервере Apache по порту 8080.
Всё работает, но...
Мне нужно http://ip_adresss/primer.php
А сейчас у меня http://ip_adress:8080/primer.php
Как подключаться по IP-адресу но не вводить порт?
Спасибо.

Comment: никак. если порт не указан, то это 80й порт по умолчанию

Comment: А если перевести апач на порт 80, то можно указав другой порт на nginxe сделать вышеупомянутое?

Comment: можно. но тогда то, что сейчас открывается на nginx будет доступно только с указанием порта. Вообще про nginx надо было сразу указать в вопросе и расипсать конфигурацию что как сейчас настроено. Возможно вам требуется настроить на nginx proxy который пробросит запросы на апач

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Мне на nginxe нужно было настроить отдачу на дополнительный ip-адрес через сокет, по-этому я прописал путь к сокету и указал в listen стандартный сервер на порту 80. Из-за чего и изменил порт на апаче. Как то так)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/120814/